# Are usability questions not related to interface allowed

Tags: discussion, question

For example:

from a uability perspective is it better to have your own login or use a third part system (OpenID, Passport, Facebook, etc...)

Is this question allowed?

Comment: I think this is perfectly fine. I don't expect to see an entire site on usability.

Comment: Also, usability is always associated to the interface. In this case it's not tied to the _GUI_, but it is part of the program's interaction with the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be allowed. Usability is really part of the experience of the user, and therefore part of the interface you offer. Besides, having a seperate site for this seems pointless because the two topics are very closely related.